# finding difference between two consecutive month data

Tags: mysql, view

I have a table - month_score with the following columns-
1.Month
2.year
3.start_date -this is the first date of every month for which score is recorded.
4.score.
the table with data would be like
'Jan'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '35'
'Feb'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '65'
'Mar'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '55'
'Apr'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '35'
'May'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '55'
'June'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '25'
'Jul'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '85'
'Aug'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '105'
'Sep'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '95'
'Oct'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '45'
'Nov'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '85'
'Dec'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '25'
'Jan'  '2013' '2012-01-02'  '65'
"
"
"
upto

'Dec'  '2014' '2012-01-02'  '35'
I need to create a view which get extract the difference between two consecutive scores like
'Jan'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '35'  '35'
'Feb'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '65'  '30'
'Mar'  '2012' '2012-01-02'  '55'  '-10'

while i am being able do this for a single year, the problem arises when the year changes.

Comment: Do you have any other columns in the table, such as a month number or id that puts the rows in order?

Comment: the start date is unique. it is the first date of each month for recorded data.

Comment: It doesn't look unique in your sample data.  It always has the same value.

Comment: You don't need to add month column in mysql. You can get it from date

Comment: currently i am using this query- select `t1`.`year` AS `year`,`t1`.`month` AS `month`,`t1`.`start_date` AS `first_date`,`t1`.`score` AS `score`,(`t1`.`score` - coalesce(`t2`.`score`,`t1`.`score`)) AS `difference` from (`monthly_scores` `t1` left join `monthly_scores` `t2` on(((`t1`.`month` = (`t2`.`month` + 1)) and (`t1`.`year` <= `t2`.`year`)))) group by `t1`.`month` order by `t1`.`year`,`t1`.`month`

Comment: @GordonLinoff - i missed editing but it's unique.

Comment: @Nikul - that is not my issue currently.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `start_date` really is the first date of each month, you an use a self join:

```
select t.*, t.score - tprev.score
from table t left join
     table tprev
     on year(t.start_date) * 12 + month(t.start_date) =
        year(tprev.start_date) * 12 + month(tprev.start_date) + 1;
```

You can do something similar with month names, but the logic is *much* more complicated.

Comment: Issue resolved. I wasn't grouping it by year. did that.